# ubuntu bionic beaver usb install stuck on beaver background

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, live-usb

I am trying to dualboot ubuntu 18.04 on my alienware pc running 64bit win10. I created an UEFI usb install and disabled secure boot. There was no trouble getting to GRUB and selecting install. But, once it got past the purple loading screen, it only shows the beaver background and nothing else.

It's been stuck for a long time.What is the problem?

even the "try ubuntu" option in grub is having the same results

Comment: Did you verify the downloaded ISO was perfect? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then validate the install media to ensure it was flawless? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD refers to any media used, be it cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/...)  If it fails to validate on that box, test on another; if it fails on two boxes the media is flawed (bad write most common issue in my experience).

Comment: Everything that can go wrong with a bootable USB drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot